# Which is the best 0auth gem for a rails app?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, oauth, oauth-ruby

I'm going to add Oauth autenthication to my rails [web app](http://nuvola.armoredcode.com). Since I don't want to reinvent the wheel, have you got some ruby gem to suggest to add this kind of feature?

TIA
Paolo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that this advice is now superseded. I'd suggest you use OmniAuth instead, possibly with Devise if you need normal auth as well.

There are 2 OmniAuth specific RailsCasts that walk you through exactly what's needed: [OmniAuth Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1) and [OmniAuth Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these:

[Pelle's plugin at github](http://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin) tutorial is [here](http://xaop.com/blog/2010/03/05/authentication-with-oauth-in-ruby-on-rails/)

and the second one is [oauth2](http://github.com/intridea/oauth2) with some [examples](http://wiki.github.com/intridea/oauth2/rails-23-webserver-example)

Petr